# Add Minutes to Time in ngFor loop angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, datetime, angular2-forms

I am creating  scheduler in which user provide input of start time and and time between two games i need to show time in loop/ngFor every time it add minutes to the time how to achieve it in angular 4 html loop

Comment: Why you want to use ngFor ? You can achieve that simply by javascript.

Comment: can you show me how to do that in JavaScript?

Comment: You need to provide some code, **it's not free coding service**

Answer (score -1):

**i thing that maybe help you**
the value will increase every one minute

```js
var increasungvalue = 1
function increase(){
  increasingvalue += 1
}
setInterval(increase,60000)
//note 60 minute in milisec...
```

Comment: Sorry my be you don't understand my question: It is a scheduler like we have 10 players registered against a event then event host enter the Start time for 1st player and tell us the time  a player need to complete game so we need to add that time in start time and show second player start time dynamicaly and so on